# How to disable horizontal scrolling in android

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I am using Horizontal scrolling in my application at some condition i don't want my horizontal scrolling to occur. so can any one help me how to disable the horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another layout in your main view , and give requestFocus() to that view.

so your scroll view will get disable.

This solution work for me in my app.